# PHP: documentElement->childNodes warning

Tags: php, domdocument

```
$xml = file_get_contents(example.com);

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$items = $dom->documentElement;

foreach($items->childNodes as $item) { 
 $childs = $item->childNodes;
 foreach($childs as $i) {
  echo $i->nodeValue . "<br />";
 }
}
```

Now I get this warning in every 2nd foreach:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file_example.php  on line 14
```

Please help guys. Thanks!

Comment: The error message suggests that `$childs` is not an iterable type. Please provide a short extract of the XML you are parsing.

Comment: @Gordon, thanks! i am bad at naming vars ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some nodes don't have children, so you're passing a null (invalid) argument to the foreach (just like the warning says).

To avoid the warnings you need to check if the current node has any children. For that you can use the [`DOMNode::hasChildNodes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.haschildnodes.php) method:

```
foreach($items->childNodes as $item) { 
    if ($item->hasChildNodes()) {
        $childs = $item->childNodes;
        foreach($childs as $i) {
            echo $i->nodeValue . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```