# php dom not interpreting php tags

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to get the value inside a div with php dom, I do get the value with the below code, but I don't get the php tags with it. php dom is not interpreting the tags, I know php dom is not supposed to interpret tags, but is there a work around to interpret the tags as well?

```
$selected_div = "wrapper";
$file = 'http://localhost/jugni/selected.php'; // $file contents  = <html><body><div id = "wrapper"><?php echo "hello world"; ?></div></body></html>
$file_get= file_get_contents($file);
$doc = new DomDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$doc->loadHTML($file_get);
$element = $doc->getElementById($selected_div);
$existing_Data = $element->firstChild->nodeValue;
echo $existing_Data;
//echo $existing_Data gives me  - hello world - , but what I want is the php tags with it as well , eg < ? php echo "hello world "; ?>
```

Comment: So, actually you want `<?php` and `?>` in your `$file_get= file_get_contents($file);` as well?

Comment: @Testing , yes , is there a way to get that , < ? php and ? >

Answer (score 0):

By the time you use `$file_get= file_get_contents($file);` the php has already been executed on the server side and only its output is present in $file_get. The raw php would not be present at that point.

Comment: I suggest reconsidering why you need to find the php tags. Please explain the end result you are looking for, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: it just not the php tags, it doesnt show any tags, eg. if i have a < h1 > tag inside the div, it wont show that either, i need to get this done .. please lemme know if there is a way

Comment: Ah, if you need to grab the HTML tags within the div then you need to use more of the tools in the DomNode class http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php. HTML tags inside the div are child nodes, they don't show up in the div node's value. You need to get the child nodes and then iterate over them. There are many examples on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511779/php-documentelement-childnodes-warning